# Text slightly under navigation bar in autolayout

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

On some screens the label inside a StackView partially disappears under the navigation bar. Currently I have a constraint `stackView.top = Top Layout Guide.bottom`, but it does not seem to work as I hoped. How to constrain my StackView, so that everything would be properly visible?

Comment: Try "Top space to container margin" (hold ⌥ when creating constraints in IB), or use the new [`safeAreaLayoutGuide`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide) in Xcode 9/iOS 11+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by embedding the view into navigation controller. After that the constraint started working perfectly.